# How can I find out if an ES6 value is var / const / let after it is declared?

Tags: javascript, constants, let

I know I can find out if a value is `var` `const` or `let` by looking at where it is declared. However I am wondering - mainly for debugging, developing JS compilers, and academic interest - if it is possible to find out the immutability / scope of a variable (var / const / let-ness) after it has been created.

ie

```
doThing(something)
```

Would return

```
let
```

Or equivalent. Like we can determine types with `typeof` or `something.constructor.name` for constructors.

Comment: Very good question, I don't think that in javascript there is any possible way to check whether a value is immutable or not. Also I think there is no method in javascript to just check that straight away.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio yes this does seem like a duplicate.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the use case for this?

Comment: @lewis mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can distinguish `let` and `const` from `var` with direct `eval` in the same function as the variable:

```
let a;

try {
    eval('var a');
    // it was undeclared or declared using var
} catch (error) {
    // it was let/const
}
```

As @JonasWilms had written earlier, you can distinguish `let` from `const` by attempting assignment:

```js
{
  let x = 5;
  let isConst = false;
  
  try {
    x = x;
  } catch (err) {
    isConst = true;
  }
  
  console.log(isConst ? 'const x' : 'let x');
}

{
  const x = 5;
  let isConst = false;
  
  try {
    x = x;
  } catch (err) {
    isConst = true;
  }
  
  console.log(isConst ? 'const x' : 'let x');
}
```

Comment: Interesting, you can then further check if it's writeable in a try/catch to find if it's a `const` or not, I guess.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yep. That was already covered, but now edited out for some reason…?

Comment: Weird, I didn't see that version. It's not in the history, so it might have been within the grace period (or whatever that's called).

Comment: @ry- nevermind, I missinterpreted the error I got (I was missing an initializer in the const declaration, didn't look closely at the error message)

Comment: What are the `{}` wrapping the code sections?

Comment: @mikemaccana: Blocks to scope variables. Lets the name `x` be used both times so the blocks can be identical apart from the one word.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the environment record chain in any way, and therefore you can't tell were a variable was declared. The `with` statement might enable you to narrow down the scope were a variable was declared as it allows you to add a Proxy as an environment record, but that only gives some insight and it is generally a very dangerous thing to do.

Comment: But what he wants is a functions that returns it.

Comment: This only works in `"use strict";` mode unless something has changed since.

Comment: @ricardo yup, thats even more impossible.

Answer (score 1):

let and var are only about the scope, so it's not possible. Because JavaScript does not pass by reference, if you were to pass a variable to a function you would lose the " constness" and also the scope - on that function the variable would just be a locally scoped one. So my thoughts are: it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this but its a little hacky...

I create a variable and try to change it and if it throws an error then it's a const variable,.

I create a variable and try to change it on the `{}` braces, if the value is different then it was initially created then it's a var, if not then it's a let variable.